# Помогите со знаками препинания!

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

Но вовремя одумывался это же близкий друг. Конечно не идеальный ворчит, ссоримся, но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.
(Или лучше совместить оба предложения?)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу эти предложения в таком виде:
***Но вовремя одумывался: это же близкий друг! Конечно, не идеальный (ворчит, ссоримся), но — который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.***

Или в таком:
***Но вовремя одумывался (Это же близкий друг; конечно, не идеальный: ворчит, ссоримся,— но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.).***

Или в таком:
***Но вовремя одумывался (это же близкий друг!). Конечно, не идеальный: ворчит, ссоримся,— но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.***

Вариантов здесь может быть предостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем совмещать? Короткие предложения легче воспринимаются, а "совмещать" такую разнонаправленную информацию (моя реакция самоодёргивания и характеристика отношений) можно только через точку с запятой, что интонационно очень близко к точке.

Расставляем знаки:

*Но вовремя одумывался: это же близкий друг. Конечно, не идеальный — ворчит, ссоримся, — но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.*

Comment: Конечно, не идеальный - ворчит, ссоримся, - но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.

Вызывает сомнение перечисление, разве там не нужно ставить двоеточие?

Comment: Выделение *ворчит, ссоримся* возможно разными путями. И даже скобками. Я выбрала наиболее мне симпатичный вариант. А двоеточие у нас очень близко, тем более что автор задумывается, не слить ли предложения в одно.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве варианта:

**Но вовремя одумывался: это же близкий друг! Конечно, не идеальный (ворчит, ссоримся), но который всегда сможет выручить в трудную минуту.**

Здесь важно ясно показать нестандартные однородные отношения между словом и предложением, а для этого лучше подходят скобки.